# Dynamic Serial port selection and use without instantiating all Serialx objects

Tags: serial

I have an arduino project that reads a config file from SD and then receives data on a serial port that is specifed in the config file.

I therefore need to instantiate the Serial (Serial0), Serial1,..2,3, etc based on dynamic data.

I am using a mega2560 with 4x HardwareSerial. Serial (also Serial0) is the USB. Serial 1, 2, 3 are on specific hardware pins.

I started with code something like:

```
uint8_t InitPort(uint8_t port) {
    switch (port) {
        case 0:
            if(Serial.begin(9600) return 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            if(Serial1.begin(9600) return 1;
            break;

        ... etc...

        default:
            return 0;
}
```

However, this instantiates all Serialx objects (using 157 bytes of data/bss each).

I've since written a class wrapper that takes a referece to the desired serial object as an initialising paramter, but this just pushes the problem up-stack to the calling code.

Is there a way that a Serial object can be instanitated dynamically with a port number passed in, to only end up with one instance connected to the desired port?

Comment: Do you speak about SoftwareSerial interfaces or the hardware interfaces?

Comment: they are all instanced, but optimized away if the code doesn't use it. the class of Serials depends on the board. on some boards Serial is USB and Setial1 is HardwareSerial. but on boards with 328p it is something like `HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR);`

Comment: Post editied to clarify mega2560 - hardware serial.

Comment: @Juraj they are not optimised away by the linker in my appliction (which is the problem) becuase the linker does not know which one will be use at runtime - this is based on user config data read from the SD. So it includes all 4 with assoicated memory use which is the underlying problem.

Comment: all are used in your sketch in some case, so must be in the final build.

Comment: @TisteAndii, it is not so complicated. only the instances must be created dynamically as Edgar shows in the answer

Comment: but what is 3 times 157 bytes in 8 kB SRAM of the Mega? :-)

Comment: sometimes it really matters :-) https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=622002.msg4215655#msg4215655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of `HardwareSerial` referencing a hardware
port that depends on a function parameter, as in

```c++
void initPort(uint8_t port) {
    switch (port) {
        case 0: {
            HardwareSerial serial(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L,
                     &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
            serial.begin(9600);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
            // etc...
    }
}
```

However, since only a local variable can be created in this manner, it
is not of much use. Ideally, you would want to have a *global* variable
for the serial port, and initialize it in `initPort()`, as

```c++
HardwareSerial serial;

void initPort(uint8_t port) {
    switch (port) {
        case 0:
            // Invoke fictional init() method.
            serial.init(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L,
                     &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
            break;
        case 1:
            // etc...
    }
    serial.begin(9600);
}
```

Alas, this is not possible, as the `HardwareSerial` class has no default
constructor. This means that binding the object to the hardware port can
only be done when it is constructed.

Short of modifying the Arduino core (adding a default constructor and an
`init()` method), the only option I can see is to have the global
variable be a *pointer*. Then, in `initPort()` the object is
instantiated while initializing the pointer. I tried this approach in
the example program below. There was a slight technical difficulty
though: since the object files from the core defining `Serial`,
`Serail1`, etc. will hopefully *not* be linked to the program, the
interrupt service routines defined therein must be also defined in the
sketch itself. And since an ISR cannot be bound to an interrupt at run
time, the ISRs have to be defined for *all* the ports, even though only
one ends up being actually used.

Here is my test program:

```c++
#include <HardwareSerial_private.h>

HardwareSerial *serial;

ISR(USART0_RX_vect) { serial->_rx_complete_irq(); }
ISR(USART1_RX_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_RX_vect));
ISR(USART2_RX_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_RX_vect));
ISR(USART3_RX_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_RX_vect));
ISR(USART0_UDRE_vect) { serial->_tx_udr_empty_irq(); }
ISR(USART1_UDRE_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_UDRE_vect));
ISR(USART2_UDRE_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_UDRE_vect));
ISR(USART3_UDRE_vect, ISR_ALIASOF(USART0_UDRE_vect));

void initPort(uint8_t port)
{
    switch (port) {
        case 0:
            serial = new HardwareSerial(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L,
                         &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
            break;
        case 1:
            serial = new HardwareSerial(&UBRR1H, &UBRR1L,
                         &UCSR1A, &UCSR1B, &UCSR1C, &UDR1);
            break;
        case 2:
            serial = new HardwareSerial(&UBRR2H, &UBRR2L,
                         &UCSR2A, &UCSR2B, &UCSR2C, &UDR2);
            break;
        case 3:
            serial = new HardwareSerial(&UBRR3H, &UBRR3L,
                         &UCSR3A, &UCSR3B, &UCSR3C, &UDR3);
            break;
    }
    serial->begin(9600);
}

void setup() {
    initPort(0);
    serial->println("Hello, World!");
}

void loop(){}
```

It should be noted that the ISRs do not take that mush flash space.
There are actually only two of them, even though each is referenced four
times in the interrupt vector table.

Comment: Excellent that you have shared your progression to the answer. Many thanks. Now for the next learning deep dive - understanding ISRs properly on arduino and getting accross all the U variables in the HardwareSerial class. I presume they are registers of some sort?

Comment: @BrendanMcL: If you want to dig deeper, you will have to read the chapter “USART” of the [ATmega2560 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), and the chapter “Interrupts” of the [avr-libc documentation](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html).

Comment: @BrendanMcL: The “U variables” are references to hardware I/O registers. For example, `UBRR0H` is a macro that expands to `(*(uint8_t*)0xc5)`, where `0xc5` is the memory-mapped address of the “USART0 Baud Rate Register High Byte”.

Comment: @Edgar_Bonet many thanks. Understood. Having so many great libraries on the arduino platform is a great upside for working quickly. Downside being that it abstracts away so much detail making it a full learning curve to do something outside the spec.